# Cannot backup using Duplicity via cron

Tags: bash, cron, duplicity

I am trying to run a backup script `foo.sh` via `cron`. The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PASSPHRASE=password123
duplicity ../learningbash file://../../../media/kingston
unset PASSPHRASE
```

Then I add dthe following line in "crontab -e":

```
58 07  * * * /home/ashish/learningbash/foo.sh
```

It runs perfectly when I run it from the terminal using `./foo.sh`. But it does not run from the `cron`. Also, if I edit "foo.sh" to the following code, the first line executes perfectly from the `cron`. But the backup script doesn't run.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch hello.txt

export PASSPHRASE=bacteria99
duplicity ../learningbash file://../../../media/kingston
unset PASSPHRASE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have used relative paths in your script:

```
duplicity ../learningbash file://../../../media/kingston
```

This is working from terminal because you were in the correct directory where you should be to interpret the relative paths correctly.

`cron` of an individual user sets the user's home directory as `PWD`.

To solve the issue, use absolute path e.g.:

```
duplicity /bar/learningbash file:///foo/bar/media/kingston
```

Comment: @AshishNeupane Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing expect, and setting up trusted root ssh logins on localhost to make this work.
cron calls duplicity.expect, which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# run duplicity backups script with a tty
set timeout 7200
spawn ssh -tt localhost /opt/backups/bin/duplicity.sh
expect {
  timeout {
    puts "Connection timed out"
  }
  eof {
    puts "EOF reached"
  }
  "yes/no" {
    send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
}
```

duplicity.sh contains the actual duplicity backup commands to run, and the PASSPHRASE env variable that GPG will use to encrypt them all.